# ASP.Net Core 2.2 - Method overload appears in Visual Studio but does not work at run-time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I am attempting to verify that a user is authorized via a custom policy. I followed the tutorial at [Ode To Code](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2019/05/30/evaluating-asp-net-core-authorization-policies.aspx) to add this functionality to my controller. From within Visual Studio, the code appears to be correct and utilizing a known overload.

[image: Visual Studio Screen Capture]

Notice that it says that the overload is an "extension". I didn't take much notice of this until I spent 5 hours today trying to solve the following error:

[image: Asp.net error]

As you can see, it would appear that the overload I'm attempting to use isn't being utilized. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there something special I have to do to include these extended methods? I've attempted cleaning and rebuilding the solution but this hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: I see two methods named AuthorizeAsync. `AuthorizeAsync(IAuthorizationService service, ClaimsPrincipal user, string policyName)` and `AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthorizationPolicy policy)` ... which one of those two methods are you trying to call with `AuthorizeAsync(User, "IsLucky")`?

Comment: @jPhizzle: In the extension method illustrated, the first parameter is an `IAuthorizationService`.

Comment: @EricK: The error message doesn't say that your particular overload isn't being utilized; it's saying that the object you're calling the extension method against is null.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ok, changed my comment

Comment: @jPhizzle: If you discount the first parameter (which is a `this` parameter, since it's an extension method), the actual first parameter would be a ClaimsPrincipal.  In any case, the documentation you're referring to should list the first parameter as `this IAuthorizationService service`, or somesuch.

Comment: @jPhizzle, since I only passed 2 variables, I am attempting to call `AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthorizationPolicy policy)`.

Comment: @EricK right... and `"IsLucky"` is a string.... i think it would need to be an `AuthorizationPolicy` type if you're trying to hit that overload method.

Comment: What about that null object?

Comment: @jPhizzle, I updated the VS screen capture to show the correct overload

Comment: @EricK thank you for clearing that up :-)

Comment: my next observation then would be `superAdmin` is null... and so checking `if (superAdmin.Succeeded)` then is causing the nullexception

Comment: For context, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationserviceextensions.authorizeasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_AuthorizationServiceExtensions_AuthorizeAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_IAuthorizationService_System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_System_String_) is the overload. As has been stated, the problem is there's no constructor DI for `IAuthorizationService`. You can see Scott does it in his `SecretsModel` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note the name change: such as the global variable name for IAuthorizationService `_authorization` has been prefixed with an underscore. Obviously not required, but as a good rule of thumb/good coding standard, IMO. :-)

```
public class LRController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorization;

    // you're missing this constructor & this pattern is known as Constructor Dependency Injection
    public LRController(IAuthorizationService authorization)
    {
        _authorization = authorization;
    }

    public async Task<RedirectToActionResult> Index()
    {
        var superAdmin = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(User, "IsLucky");
        //rest of your code here
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Additionally, if you wanted/needed to inject other interfaces into this controller, you would add it to that LRController constructor. Would look something like this:

```
public class LRController : Controller
{

    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorization;
    private readonly IOtherService _otherService;

    public LRController(IAuthorizationService authorization, IOtherService otherService)
    {
        _authorization = authorization;
        _otherService = otherService;
    }

    public async Task<RedirectToActionResult> Index()
    {
        var superAdmin = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(User, "IsLucky");
    }

    public async Task Foo()
    {
        await _otherService.Bar();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ya know i saw that, but for some reason didn't think it was necessary because the tutorial was building a page model. I'll attempt this as soon as i return to the office.

Answer (score 4):

While you've defined the field for `IAuthorizationSerivce`, you haven't provided any way for that to be set. You need to define a constructor for the `LRController` that takes a single parameter of `IAuthorizationService`, and assign that to the field.

I think there was a definition of that constructor in the tutorial.